Attempting to use forEach method to spread across divs
I am attempting to use the forEach method to create separate arrays so that I can create one section of data to be able to display multiple elements rather that using innerHTML.
// let movieTitle = document.getElementById("movie-title");
// let movieDesc = document.getElementById("movie-description");

    // This section will allow us to display data to the user
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        Authorization:
          // "Bearer Keys Go here
      },
    };
    
    async function getTrendingFilms() {
      try {
        // Fetch data from the API
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?include_adult=false&include_video=false&language=en-US&page=1&sort_by=popularity.desc",
          options // Pass options to fetch
        );
    
        // Check if the response is successful
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Could not fetch resource");
        }
    
        // Parse response data as JSON
        const data = await response.json();
    
        // 
        const results = data.results
        console.log(results)
    
        const titleElement = document.getElementById("movie-title");
        const overviewElement = document.getElementById("movie-description")
        
        // Iterate through the first 6 movies and display their titles
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          // Create a new div element for each movie title
          console.log(results[i].original_title)
    
    
          // Set the inner HTML of the div to the original title of the movie
                titleElement.innerHTML = results[i].original_title;
                overviewElement.innerHTML = results[i].overview;


      // Append the title element to the document body or any other desired container
    }

  } catch (err) {
    // Handle errors
    console.error(err);
}
}

getTrendingFilms();

On the comments below, I created a new variable for each section I wanted to overwrite the element. However, instead of making lots of variables, I want to try to make a better method as the data contains the whole array. Thank you for the time to read.

Should it help to see the array of data. I am using: https://developer.themoviedb.org/reference/discover-movie

Where are you trying to use the forEach() method?

You can simply replace the for loop with data.forEach(movieTitle => console.log(movietitle))

Don't use commented code to show your problem. Post the code you're having trouble with as a real function. We don't need to see the code that works, just the problem code.

Yes. And if I wanted to append the info from one endpoint across multiple Divs on the HTML, Would I first make a variable to store each endpoint to target?

Not sure of the wording, but I am looking to parse out the data in their own separate arrays so I can add them to a unique DIV

Please show sample data and the desired result. The AJAX call is not relevant, just start with let data = [ sample values ].

Hope this code helps:
async function getTrendingFilms() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?include_adult=false&include_video=false&language=en-US&page=1&sort_by=popularity.desc",
      options
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Could not fetch resource");
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    const results = data.results;

    const moviesContainer = document.getElementById("movies-container");

    // Generate HTML for movies
    results.forEach((movie) => {
      // Create elements for the movie title and overview
      const titleElement = document.createElement("h2");
      titleElement.textContent = movie.original_title;

      const overviewElement = document.createElement("p");
      overviewElement.textContent = movie.overview;

      // Create a container div for each movie
      const movieDiv = document.createElement("div");
      movieDiv.classList.add("movie");

      // Append title and overview elements to the movie div
      movieDiv.appendChild(titleElement);
      movieDiv.appendChild(overviewElement);

      // Append the movie div to the container
      moviesContainer.appendChild(movieDiv);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

getTrendingFilms();

